Azure Data Factory: Use Array Variable as Data Source in Copy Data
I have used a web activity and got a nested JSON response. I want to save the data in Azure SQL Server. I am not sure how to use the web activity response as a data source.
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        "ColData": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "value"
            ]
            }
        },
        },
    }
}


Can you provide the information about how the web activity output is looking like? Can you provide the activities that you are trying to use?

Can you provide nested JSON structure and target SQL table structure?

@RakeshGovindula
I have attached the JSON Schema to the question. But the point is, I just want to understand, how do I use the variable as data source. If I understand that, I will navigate through nested array.
I am going to try and copy the variable in csv and then use that as source. I will update once its complete

You can achieve your requirement in following ways based on the structure of your source JSON and target table structure.

Using copy activity mapping:
If your source JSON structure is simple JSON array, you can try this approach.
Use HTTP or REST linked services for your URL and take it as copy activity source.
If it is a HTTP, take JSON dataset.

In the copy activity sink, give your target table dataset. Go to mapping and import schemas.

Here, you can import schemas of both source and target. After importing, uncheck Advanced editor and select your JSON array from the Collection reference. You can remove the extra column mappings and set the data types of the target as well. You need to do this as per target table structure. After setting the mapping, debug the copy activity and the required data will be copied to the target table.

Using web activity and stored procedure:
If your JSON is nested and complex, you can try this approach.
First get the JSON response using web activity in ADF. In the target database, create a stored procedure which can handle the JSON and insert the data into your table.
For sample, I have created a stored procedure like below which inserts data from a JSON array.
create or alter procedure dbo.sp3(@myjson varchar(max))
as
begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@myjson, '$')
with (
    userId int '$.userId',
    id int '$.id',
    title varchar(max) '$.title',
    body varchar(max) '$.body'
);
end

You can use openjson and JSON_VALUE to select the required fields from the JSON string.
After creating the stored procedure use a Stored procedure activity to call this from ADF. Pass the web activity response JSON as JSON string to this stored procedure parameter.
@string(json(activity('Web1').output.Response))



Using Dataflow:
As your target is Azure SQL, you can use Mapping Dataflow as well. Create a REST linked service with your API and use it as Dataflow source. In the dataflow, you can use transformations like Flatten to flatten the JSON array and select transformation to remove the extra columns. After transforming to required structure, add the target table as sink of the dataflow. Debug the dataflow from the ADF pipeline using dataflow activity and data will be copied to target table.


